# IN STOCK FILTER FOR Magento 2 Product collection

Tags: product, collection, filter, magento2.2.2, stock

i am trying to filter inStock product in Magento 2 Using 
I am trying to filter inStock product in Magento 2 Using

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,

by

```
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        //$collection->addAttributeToFilter('rand()');
        //$collection->addAttributeToFilter('flavor',$flavorId);
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $searchCategory]);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
        $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
        $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
        $collection->setPageSize(3);
        $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
        $collection->joinField(
        'qty', 'csvp_cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=2', 'left'
            );
        //$collection->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', 'qty=0');
        return $collection;
```

but the result is also shown out of stock products.
can any one suggest me how to get only in stock products collection.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try below code

```
$pCollection = $this->getObjectManager()->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
        $pCollection->setStoreId($storeId);
        $pCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $pCollection->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE));
        $pCollection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
$pCollection->joinField(
    'stock_status', 'cataloginventory_stock_status', 'stock_status', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
)->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', array('eq' => \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this class \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock

```
 $stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Comment: This one causes strange issues. It adds an inner join with 

    AND (
  (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1) 
        OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=0) 
        OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1)
 )

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $searchCategory]);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
        $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
        $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
        $collection->setPageSize(3);
        $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
        $collection->joinField(
        'qty', 'csvp_cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=2', 'left'
            );

        $collection->getSelect()->where('csvp_stock_status_index.stock_status = ?', 1);

        return $collection;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        //$collection->addAttributeToFilter('rand()');
        //$collection->addAttributeToFilter('flavor',$flavorId);
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $searchCategory]);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
        $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
        $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
        $collection->setPageSize(3);
        $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();

        $collection->joinField('stock_item', 'csvp_cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', 'qty=0');
        ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
        ->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', ['eq' => 1])
        return $collection;
```

Comment: How is the "addFieldToFilter()"-Method handling the conditions? When I am using it (for 'more products of brand'), it does not seem to change anything in the output. When I use "inner"-join and extend the condition there, it does.