# How to filter product by stock quantity?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, products

I am trying to get results of products by stock quantity filter

i use this inside the constructor of my helper class.

```
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $product_lib
```

The question is how do i add stock quantity from and to in this?

```
$this->product_lib->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->
addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => array(1,2,3))->
addFieldToFilter('price', ['from' => $min_price, 'to' => $max_price])
->load();
```

When i try to additional addFieldToFilter with quantity it says not found. What i am looking for is to achieve the same results as in catalog->products filter.

Any suggestion is helpful.
Also if possible can you suggest where to do i look for these kinds of information? Is there any book that would be helpful?

Comment: you means product filter using in stock quantity??? If yes check this link ---https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215617/in-stock-filter-for-magento-2-product-collection

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want to get all products where stock_quantity >= $min_quantity and stock_quantity <= $max_quantity. But the above link seems to check if product is in status or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** @var ProductCollection $collection */
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        'qty>0'
    );
```